# How do i connect to mysql server? and what do i use for the parameters?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Im trying to create a login for my website and i need to store emails, usernames, passwords, ect in a database i have created already using phpMyAdmin.  I have gone through article after article and nothing seems to be working.  i have my connect.php like this:

```
<?
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$databaseName = "_mySiteUserDataBase";

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db($databaseName) or die("Cannot select database");
?>
```

And my main.php like this:

```
<?
include("connect.php");

$tableName = "myUsers";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

And i have created a simple form in my html like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type = "submit" action = "main.php" method = "post" value = "Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After submitting the form it says cannot connect to server.  I am new to php and mysql and i dont understand what each parameter in the mysql_connect is, and i dont know what they do therefore im not sure what im supposed to enter in but everyone i keep reading about seems to be inputing random values?  I could use a brief explanation on that, because i am stuck at connecting and cant even get past this point sadly enough.  Also i have been reading that mysql_connect is deprecated and isnt valid anymore but i dont understand what im supposed to use as an alternative.  I know its mysqli but thats it and im unclear of the syntax.

Comment: Is your username and password to connect to your server is `username` and `password`? And use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) rather than the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*`.

Comment: as @LoganWayne said, and because you are new to it anyway, start with mysqli or pdo. They are cool.

Comment: no im not sure what is it.  I dont know where to find that information and ok i will try mysqli

Comment: The code snippet looks fine. Is it possible that the credentials are simply wrong? If not, try replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` and see if that works.

Regarding mysqli: The laziest way would be to replace all `mysql_*` instances with their `mysqli_*` counterpart, but I think the object-oriented style would be a better practice. Here’s a code example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples

Comment: You can look for the username in your PhpMyAdmin page. But usually, beginners that follow a simple instruction has the username set to `root` and does not have a password. Maybe you can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me convert it to mysqli for you and maybe that will fix the problem. Also, make sure the username, password, and database name are correct.

Try this code. At very least, it will provide a better error message for debugging.

```
<?
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$databaseName = "_mySiteUserDataBase";

$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName) or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

Main.php

```
<?
include("connect.php");

$tableName = "myUsers";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

Comment: where can i find my username and password?

Comment: You said you have already used phpMyAdmin to administor your database? It should be the same username and password. If you use cPanel or another hosting panel, meaning you just click phpMyadmin button and it logs you in automatically, you can get your username and password following this article (do step 1 with your own hosts panel): http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/reset-database-password

Comment: ahh thank you thats what i was looking for.  i didnt recieve any errors this time around.  thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**mysqli:**

```
<?php
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    echo "start<br/>";
    try {
        $mysqli= new mysqli('localhost', 'myusername', 'mypassword', 'dbname');
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        echo "I am connected and feel happy.<br/>";
        $mysqli->close();
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    } 
?>
```

If you need to know how to create users, what the heck the hostname is, how to grant access (often useful after the connect :>), just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in 'connect.php'

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');// here 'root' is your username and "" is password

if(!$con)

{
echo 'not connect';die;

}

mysql_select_db('dbname',$con);// here 'dbname' is your database name


?>
```

And also try following code to include sql connection in your other php file(main.php)

```
<?php 

    include 'connect.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myUsers";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```